# Accessing ImageButton Contents

Tags: c#, wpf, imagebutton

I am representing a Solar-System's planets with ImageButtons that show the planet's image on the surface of the button, and hold the planet's important data.. name, distance from sun, etc within an instance of a `Planet` class, stored within the `ImageButton.Content` property.  When the `ImageButton` is selected, I am attempting to access and display the `Planet` class's data for the selected `Planet`.  Although `((ImageButton)e.OriginalSource).Content` permits viewing all of the `Planet` class's properties in the debugger, I haven't figured out how to access the Planet class properties directly, as in `Pluto.DistanceFromTheSun`?  Is it possible to access the Planet class information held in the `ImageButton` contents directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably you just need another cast:

```
((Planet)((ImageButton)e.OriginalSource).Content).DistanceFromTheSun
```

where Planet is the class that Pluto is.

Comment: Thank you SLC.  That's exactly it.
Bill